# Difference between DataContractSerializer and DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between **DataContractSerializer** and **DataContractJsonSerializer**?
 There is any difference in class, use and speed at all?

Comment: -1: You really try to read MSDN description before asking question. I.e. speed is rarely concern when operations are significantly different...

Comment: Sure MSDN help a lot, unfortunately on this one, beside saying one is for JSON and another is for XML nothing more said about it... really poor documentation. @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: Well this question is the top hit on google now, so I'm glad that it got an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

straight from the MSDN

DataContractSerializer---Serializes and deserializes an instance of a type into an **XML** stream or document using a supplied data contract. This class cannot be inherited.

DataContractJsonSerializer---Serializes objects to the **`JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)`** and deserializes JSON data to objects. This class cannot be inherited.

in speed I think json might be faster

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the obvious serialization format differences, there are also limitations as to what the respective serializer is capable of handling.

In particular, `DataContractSerializer` is capable of handling [circular references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh241056.aspx) by setting the `IsReference` property of the `DataContractAttribute` constructor to `true`. `DataContractJsonSerializer` is not able to handle this scenario since there is no standardized representation of references in JSON [(according to the `WriteObject` error message)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19979082/650012).