# Can DataContractJsonSerializer handle cyclic references?

Tags: c#, .net, json, datacontractserializer, datacontractjsonserializer

Are there any serialization/deserialization scenarios that [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) *can* handle, while [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) *can't*?

In particular, I am thinking of circular references: [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh241056.aspx) explains how circular references can be managed by `DataContractSerializer` via the use of `IsReference = true` in the `DataContractAttribute` constructor. On the other hand, the [DataContractAttribute.IsReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.isreference.aspx) documentation does not explicitly state that its applicability is limited to `DataContractSerializer`.

Will `DataContractJsonSerializer` also honor the `IsReference` property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing like a good old hands-on testing in the afternoon...

When applying `DataContractAttribute.IsReference = true` on the class subject to serialization,

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class SerializableClass {
...
}
```

and trying to serialize it using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`,

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SerializableClass));
serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
```

The `WriteObject` method will throw an exception:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : The type 'SerializableClass' cannot be serialized to JSON because its IsReference setting is 'True'. The JSON format does not support references because there is no standardized format for representing references. To enable serialization, disable the IsReference setting on the type or an appropriate parent class of the type.

If I on the other hand use `DataContractSerializer` to serialize the same object, serialization (and deserialization) works like a charm.

**Now**, if anyone knows of more limitations of `DataContractJsonSerializer` in comparison with `DataContractSerializer`, I am all ears...